# how to provide a suitable fitness function - Genetic Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, genetic-algorithm

i am struggling to understand how to calculate fitness function 
for example i need to know what is the suitable fitness function for the binary sequence in present case and in the general case using mathematical notation (summation notation) and please with to do the calculations

P = (1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)

Thanks

Comment: If you have a candidate solution, then the fitness function calculates how well this solution solves the task. It is impossible to tell you the fitness function without knowing what the goal is.

Comment: a fitness function is how you judge success so you will need a way to measure success based on current difference between assessed value versus its desired end state  ... so for example if goal is to reach zero when subtracting two variables its fitness function would simply take the absolute value of the two variables as in  abs(varA - varB)